# Fedora 19 x86_64 kernel version is different with kernel source

Tags: linux, kernel, fedora

I installed Fedora 19 x86_64 on My vmware workstation.  When I try to install the third party software. it give me a message "can't find kernel source files".

I checked that the kernel version is 3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64 via uname -r.

but I found the kernel source version is higher than the current running kernel version.

there are two symblic links in /lib/modules/3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64 folder. they are

build -> /usr/src/kernels/3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64
source -> build

They are broken, because there is no folder  /usr/src/kernels/3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64 in my system.

Can anyone tell me why this situation happens. and how to install correct kernel source in my Fedora.

Big thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong, but VMWare ask you wich os you want to install when creating the VM, you may have putted the wrong version/a unsupported version?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason to not run the latest kernel?  You might benefit from updating everything first.

```
#  yum update
```

Doubt you actually need the entire kernel source.  Have you installed kernel-devel?

```
#  yum install kernel-devel
```

If you need more, next install kernel headers.

```
#  yum install kernel-headers
```

If you do update the running kernel, reboot into that kernel before installing the 3rd party software.

Comment: I had a similar issue with VirtualBox. Not sure why, but the installed kernel headers and the running kernel weren't the same version. Running these commands solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here what is the currently most stable kernel available (and download associated RPMs if you requiere):

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/kernel

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me on my Fedora 19 box and my kernel version was: 3.14.4-100.fc19.x86_64 so VirtualBox was looking for the source here:

```
/usr/src/kernels/3.14.4-100.fc19.x86_64
```

I checked my /usr/src/kernels dir which and found that it was empty. Then I downloaded the kernel src from the net which was named:

```
kernel-3.14.4-100.fc19.**src**.rpm
```

and extracted to /usr/src/kernels/ and run:

```
/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Which returned:

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                      [  OK  ]
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                         [  OK  ]
```

Was working great!